# bootstrap 3 : responsive content div in modal box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I add jquery location picker into content box of bootstrap modal 3. with `height:400px;` and `width:500px` Like This :

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Location:
                <input type="text" id="us2-address" style="width: 200px" />Radius:
                <input type="text" id="us2-radius" />
                <div id="us2" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>Lat.:
                <input type="text" id="us2-lat" />Long.:
                <input type="text" id="us2-lon" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-changes">Save changes</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to create responsive google map div (`id="us2"`) in modal box. how to create this ?

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Lzv7w/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the width property from the style attribute of the div with id="us2" , as below

```
<div id="us2" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Lzv7w/2/